# Why does SQL Server 2005 think COUNT(...) is nullable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I do

```
CREATE VIEW Test1 AS
WITH OneRow AS (SELECT a = 1)
SELECT countt = COUNT(*)
FROM OneRow

GO

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Test1'
```

I get

```
COLUMN_NAME IS_NULLABLE
----------- -----------
     countt         YES
```

I would have expected `IS_NULLABLE` to be `NO`, though, since I thought that `COUNT(*)` always returns a number.

Are there circumstances in which `COUNT(*)` could return `NULL`?  Is there any danger wrapping it up as `ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)`?  It seems odd that that would be necessary.  Indeed, is there any scenario in which `COUNT(`*anything*`)` could return `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your specific case will ever see a NULL in that computed column, and I don't think there's a problem in wrapping the column in ISNULL().  SQL Server typically reports computed columns as NULLABLE.

From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191250.aspx:

> The Database Engine automatically determines the nullability of
>   computed columns based on the expressions used. The result of most
>   expressions is considered nullable even if only nonnullable columns
>   are present, because possible underflows or overflows will produce
>   null results as well. Use the COLUMNPROPERTY function with the
>   AllowsNull property to investigate the nullability of any computed
>   column in a table. An expression that is nullable can be turned into a
>   nonnullable one by specifying ISNULL(check_expression, constant),
>   where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result.

Comment: If you quote things, use a `>` to quote it properly (or the blockquote button). Otherwise you will be flagged for copyright violation.

Comment: In other words, the column is *technically* nullable, but it should never return a null.

Comment: "the engine determines the nullability of computed columns based on the expressions used" - that quote implies that if a column expression is comprised of only `NOT NULL`-able sub-expressions and performs no operations that could result in `NULL`  itself that the result-type is `NOT NULL` - so far, so good. But, as far as I know, `COUNT(*)` _never_ returns `NULL` and there's nothing in the docs covering this behaviour either - so what explanation is there besides it being a _major undocumented shortcoming_ in the derived-type-analysis?

Comment: @Dai - `COUNT` can return `NULL`

Comment: @MartinSmith I asked Microsoft, [they're still trying to find out for me](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7088)

Comment: @Dai I provided a demo of it returning NULL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70558507/73226

Answer (score 0):

> Why does SQL Server 2005 think COUNT(...) is nullable?

Take a look at the example below

```
CREATE VIEW Test1 AS
WITH R216 AS
(
SELECT TOP (216) 1 AS X
FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS X
FROM R216 a, R216 b, R216 c, R216 d
```

This is much the same as your example. The `COUNT` column is projected from the view

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Test1'
```

Returns

```
+-------------+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME | IS_NULLABLE |
+-------------+-------------+
| X           | YES         |
+-------------+-------------+
```

It is possible to see that this can actually return a `NULL` as below.

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT OFF;

SELECT * FROM Test1
```

Returns

```
+------+
|  X   |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

The `COUNT` of `2,176,782,336` overflows an `INT` and the use of the deprecated options `SET` above means that `NULL` is returned rather than error

Wrapping with `ISNULL(,not_null_constant)` means that the column can be seen as never returning `NULL`.

The above also applies to constructs like `ROW_NUMBER` (or pretty much any maths expression) which can return `NULL` rather than overflow as above.

In general determining nullability correctly of calculated columns can be tricky even without obscure deprecated `SET` options.

For example `MAX(not_null_column)` can also never return `NULL` when used as a vector aggregate (with a `GROUP BY`) - however it *can* return `NULL` when used as a scalar aggregate against an empty table.

In the vast majority of cases SQL Server just assumes that any calculated expression can be nullable and explicitly calls this out in the documentation with a suggestion to use `ISNULL` in cases where this assumption might cause a problem.

Comment: But if `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON`, then `COUNT` won't overflow, just error, then - and so shouldn't return `NULL` then...?

Comment: Yep. But the system tables don't store different nullability values for different set options. They will return the same value regardless.  COUNT can return NULL dependent on session options when it is SELECTed from so it would be incorrect to indicate that this column is not nullable

Comment: To be clear though because of edge cases like this most times SQL Server will just assume expressions are nullable unless they are wrapped in ISNULL rather than any exhaustive logic to determine this so there will be plenty of cases where the column is seen as nullable and no such counter example is possible but for COUNT it is possible for it to produce a NULL